# React Items wont render using Router

Tags: reactjs, django, routes

I am using routes in a react/django app and I have components that will not render.

This is my app.js which renders my homepage.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import HomePage from "./Homepage";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    console.log("App Here");
    return (
        <HomePage />
    );
  }
}

const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
render(<App />, appDiv);
```

This is my homepage.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import RoomJoinPage from "./RoomJoinPage";
import { Routes, Route, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

export default class HomePage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        console.log("homePage Here")
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<p>Test</p>} />
                    <Route path="/join" element={<RoomJoinPage />} />
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

And this is a component I am trying to render:

```
import React from "react";

export default function RoomJoinPage() {
  console.log("RoomJoinPage component is rendering.");
  return <h1>Room Join Page</h1>;
}
```

I have it working with HTML, and have narrowed it down to the routing issue. Any insight would be helpful. Thanks!

I have tried various different routing configurations. My versions are: "react": "^18.2.0", "react-router-dom": "^6.17.0". I would like the components to render on the correct routing.

Comment: I've created a [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-1zhusx?file=src%2FRoomJoinPage.tsx) width your code and the same dependency versions. Here it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove "/" from /join
<Route path="/join" element={} />
Where are you changing the route? Are you using <Link to?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).